# How to force parseInt to return NaN on any string occourence?

Tags: javascript, type-conversion

For example if we say:

```
parseInt("128"); // => 128
```

Works flawlessly.

If we say:

```
parseInt("a128"); // => NaN
```

But if we say:

```
parseInt("123a"); // => 128 again :(
```

Is there an explicit way to parse the number only and if any alphabet character appears in the argument, it would return `NaN`?

Comment: Are you trying to check if a string does not contain numbers only?

Comment: Trying to parse the number and to not to ignore the alphabets. If an alphabet char appears, it would return a NaN.

Comment: You could use `Number()` instead.

Comment: You could just do `if (!foo.test(/^\d+$/)) bar = NaN`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for your scenario where you need to deal with string you can use **Number** function as well.**Number()** function converts the object argument to a number that represents the object's value

```js
   
//test cases
console.log( Number("123") );
console.log( Number("123a") );
console.log( Number("a123") );
```

Answer (score 2):

`parseInt` doesn't work this way, check the [specs](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-parseint-string-radix).

1. It removes leading and trailing spaces.
2. If a character is encountered which isn't interpreted as integer and isn't supported by radix, then it is ignored

However you can force it work this way by doing

```js
    (function(){
            var old = parseInt;
            parseInt = function(x, y){
                if ( ( !y || y == 10 ) && isNaN( Number(x) ) ) { return NaN }
                return old.apply(this, arguments)
            }
    })();

//test cases
console.log( parseInt("123") );
console.log( parseInt("123a") );
console.log( parseInt("123a", 16) );
console.log( parseInt("a123") );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the function yourself as well:

```
function in_array (array, key){
    var check = false;
    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        if(key == array[i]){
            check = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return check;
}

var allowedchars=["0","1","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"];

function checkIsStringNaN (str){
    var b = true;
    for(var i = 0, i < str.length; i++){
        if(!in_array(allowedchars, str.charAt(i))){
            b = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(!b) {
        return NaN;
    } else {
        return parseInt(str);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you expect to have?

```
function checkIsStringNaN (str) {
  return isNaN(str) ? NaN : parseInt(str)
}

checkIsStringNaN("128") // 128
checkIsStringNaN("a128") // NaN
checkIsStringNaN("123a") // NaN
```